# How to send email from the command line with specified sender on Debian Wheezy with Exim4?

Tags: linux, email, debian, exim

I have search for ages trying to find out how to do this:

How can I send email from the command line and specify the sender address on a box with Debian 7.8 and Exim4?

This does not work:

```
mail -s "Subject of the Email" recipent_address@example.com -- -f from_user@example.com
```

Neither does this:

```
mail -s "Subject of the Email" -r from_user@example.com recipent_address@example.com
```

Comment: Which mail/mailx do you use? `update-alternatives --display mailx`

Comment: `update-alternatives --display mailx  
    mailx - auto modus  
      lenke peker for øyeblikket til /usr/bin/bsd-mailx  
    /usr/bin/bsd-mailx - prioritet 50
      slave Mail: /usr/bin/bsd-mailx
      slave Mail.1.gz: /usr/share/man/man1/bsd-mailx.1.gz
      slave mail: /usr/bin/bsd-mailx
      slave mail.1.gz: /usr/share/man/man1/bsd-mailx.1.gz
      slave mailx.1.gz: /usr/share/man/man1/bsd-mailx.1.gz
    Nåværende «beste» versjon er «/usr/bin/bsd-mailx»`

Comment: Try the `sendmail -t <msg` command, where `msg` contains the "To:", "From:", "Subject:" headers, an empty line, and the message text.

Answer (score 1):

I alwais use `mailx` for sending mail from the command line for example from crontab, procmail and so on.

Mailx comes with package bsd-mailx.

```
echo "This is the mail body" | \
mailx -s "This is the subject" recipient1@test.org recipient2@test.org
```

Answer (score 0):

Exim unlike "sendmail by endmail.org" makes `-f` option available by default only to selected local users.  [Exim Doc - Trusted Users](http://www.exim.org/exim-html-current/doc/html/spec_html/ch-the_exim_command_line.html#SECTtrustedadmin)

You can change [Exim configuration](http://www.exim.org/exim-html-current/doc/html/spec_html/ch-main_configuration.html) to:

- make the OS user trusted (`trusted_user`) or make selected OS group trusted (`trusted_groups`) [but read about other things it allows]
- allow all users to use `-f` (`untrusted_set_sender`)

Comment: According to that link root is both a trusted user and an admin user. I tested the commands as root.